# Algorithm to Learn a Regular Expression Pattern

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, algorithm

Okay... so this may be a stretch. 
I'd like to feed a List of TextStrings to a function and 
then it would return the regular expression syntax back to me. 
I'm working with a pattern of Tags or Tags for Items to be tracked. 
I'd like to to be able to detect all the possible patterns that exist. 
I thought a regular expression that could sum it up would be great.

Is this something that has been done before.

I'm working in VB.NET C# suggestions are fine to.

Maybe this is a poor programming design. But mostly wanted to now where to start searching? 
What would I even lookup under google?

Or can you offer me some direction on how to design a function like this?

Comment: `Return ".*"` - here it is. This is a part of a function that returns regex pattern that matches the strings you've passed

Comment: This seems better suited to a machine learner or a PGM.  But thsoe are harder.

Comment: actually... are you looking for a regex that matches an exact set of strings or a regex that matches a set of strings *and* all strings "similar" to those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question.  Not sure if there is a good answer or not but this was the first thing that came to mind:

```
Loop through each target string
    Loop through each character in each target string
       Categorize that character as precisely as possible.  7 = \d, f=[a-z] etc
       Create a list of the categories for each character in order.
       Add that list of categories to a list of lists
    End character loop
End target string loop
```

Attempt to use your List of category lists to determine a regex that will match all target strings.  For example if your List of Category Lists looks like this:

```
\d,\d,\d,[a-z],[a-z]
\d,\d,\d,[a-z],[a-z]
\d,\d,[a-z],[a-z]
```

You may be able to determine your regex needs match two to three digits followed by two lower case letters.  Not a whole lot to go off of, but maybe a place to start?  I'd be interested to see if you come up with a working solution...

Comment: Yah Thanks... Abe. This gives me a good start. I can see how this is can be applied in so many different ways depending on the desired end result.

Answer (score 0):

While the `.*` is a funny comment, the question becomes more interesting if you add the constraint that it be a minimal regex (for some cost metric per operator) that accepts all of the data but no other data.

Which leads to the next problem: your data probably doesn't reflect all of the examples, so what you *really* are looking for is dividing the data by classes (character, numeric, symbol). Even that is going to be difficult though: what if you really care about character casing in one instance, but not in another. What if some symbols are delimiters and others separators and still others part of the data.

In other words, given enough restrictions you can do a breadth first search through the possible regular expressions (in your limited grammar) and when you find one that works you can stop. If that is realistic in your particular use-case would depend highly on those restrictions... it isn't realistic in the unrestricted case of general regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts on the matter:

**Problem statement**

Given a finite set S of finite strings S1..Sn, find a regular expression that matches these strings in their entirety, and no other strings, avoiding the trivial solution ^S1|S2|S3|..|Sn$

**Observations**

We cannot have '.' character classes or '+', '*' or '{x,}' quantifiers, since those will allow matching of strings outside the input set.

**Algorithm**

```
# strings and collections indexed from 1

regex := "^" + make_regex(S) + "$"

function make_regex(Ss)

    # string -> length
    Ls := { length Ss[i] | 1 <= i <= n } 

    # set of starting characters
    Cs := unique { Ss[i][1] | i in 1..n L[i] >= 1 } 
    cl := last in Cs

    ret := "("
    For c in Cs

        # substrings of all non-empty strings that start with c
        Scs := { S[i][2..] | i in 1..n, L[i] >= 1, S[i][j] = c }
        ret := ret + c + make_regex(Scs) 

        If c != cl
            ret := ret + "|"
        End

    End

    If Ss contains ""
        ret := ret + "|()"

    End
    ret := ret + ")"
    return ret
End
```

**Input**

```
abc
abcd
cde
cef
```

**Result**

```
^(a(b(c(d|())))|c(d(e)|e(f)))$
```

I believe this is O(n*Lmax) as finding the regex for a unique string is linear wrt to its length. However, the more common prefixes in the input set, the closer it will be to O(Lmax) and so will be matching against the result - much faster than ^S1|S2|..|Sn$, which is O(n*Lmax).

Comment: however, stuffing all possibilities into a hashtable and checking with that is even more efficient

Comment: I read the OP's problem as getting a regex that matches the input strings and "similar" strings, for some as-yet-undefined notion of similarity. As @staafl pointed out, the problem you're solving is somewhat silly because the results are not especially interpretable and it's less efficient than a hash table or maybe a trie lookup.