# Diffing many texts against each other to derive template and data (finding common subsequences)

Tags: algorithm, diff, data-mining, lcs

Suppose there are many texts that are known to be made from a single template (for example, many HTML pages, rendered from a template backed by data from some sort of database). A very simple example:

```
id:937 name=alice;
id:28 name=bob;
id:925931 name=charlie;
```

Given only these 3 texts, I'd like to get original template that looks like this:

```
"id:" + $1 + " name=" + $2 + ";"
```

and 3 sets of strings that were used with this template:

- $1 = `937`, $2 = `alice`
- $1 = `28`, $2 = `bob`
- $1 = `925931`, $3 = `charlie`

In other words, "template" is a list of the common subsequences encountered in all given texts always in a certain order and everything else except these subsequences should be considered "data".

I guess the general algorithm would be very similar to any LCS (longest common subsequence) algorithm, albeit with different backtracking code, that would somehow separate "template" (characters common for all given texts) and "data strings" (different characters).

Bonus question: are there ready-made solutions to do so?

Comment: If in your example you have only 1th and 3th line, then digit "9" will be supposed to be part of template. Any time when you processing texts they derived from one template (only 1 template for whole set of files, no files that are not derived from template) ?

Comment: You will probably need some better heuristics or larger data set than just a few rows though. What if the second row had `name=lee;`, a basic "common substrings" would find that all the strings ends with `e;`, and lop off the `e`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to Learn a Regular Expression Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117551/algorithm-to-learn-a-regular-expression-pattern)

Comment: That's right, smaller number of input texts will yield more false positives (i.e. data detected as parts of template). I'd like to use this algorithm with hundreds / thousands of texts from a single template, so it probably won't be an issue in practice. It's ok if this algorithm will somehow fail (or return garbage) when there's no single template for all the input texts.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: The question you've mentioned is *very* unclearly defined. If that question means "construct regular expression that will pass only given strings and nothing else" then it's trivial - alternative `(A|B|C|...)` regexp or it's FSM-done optimization. If that question means "any regular expression that will pass given strings", then it's also trivial `.*`. That question really needs more constraints.

Comment: Yes, but most probably, the author of that question wants to do the same thing that you ask for, so it's essentially the same question. Except that you don't go for full regular expressions, but substring patterns only.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments about the question being ill-defined.  It seems likely that the format is much more specific than your general question indicates.

Having said that, something like [RecordBreaker](http://cloudera.github.io/RecordBreaker/) might be a help.  You could also Google "wrapper induction" to see if you find some useful leads.

Comment: RecordBreaker looks interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Perform a global [multiple sequence alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_sequence_alignment), and then call every resulting column that has a constant value part of the template:

```
                   id:   937 name=alice  ;
                   id: 28    name=bob    ;
                   id:925931 name=charlie;
Inferred template: XXX      XXXXXX       X
```

Most tools that I'm aware of for multiple sequence alignment require smaller alphabets -- DNA or protein -- but hopefully you can find a tool that works on the alphabet you're using (which presumably is at least all printable ASCII characters).  In the worst case, you can of course implement the DP yourself: to align 2 sequences (strings) globally you use the [Needleman-Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm), while for more than two sequences there are several approaches, the most common being sum-of-pairs scoring.  The exact algorithm for k > 2 sequences unfortunately takes time exponential in k, but the heuristics employed in bioinformatics tools such as [MUSCLE](http://www.drive5.com/muscle/) are much faster, and produce alignments that are very nearly as good.  If they can be persuaded to work with the alphabet you're using, they would be the natural choice.